# How can i test the dynamic json expression in my Logic app

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I'm setting up a complex json expression to build up a request for an api.  I would like to verify this expression somehow in a unittest.

Is there a library available that i can feed a json and the expression and it executes the expression so i can verify the result.

My expression contains various 'if', 'concat', 'json' statements.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add more details like, if you want to test the json in the request body for the api you have.  Also refer this MS DOC:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/test-logic-apps-mock-data-static-results?tabs=consumption may it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any external library, but any expression can be easily tested in a Logic App by creating a [`Compose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) action, using your expression in its Inputs box, running the Logic App and checking the Outputs.

Comment: Thanks, but this involves me changing the logic app. I'm looking for a library that allows me to write a unit test with a json as input and allows me to execute the expression and verify the result.

Comment: If you don't want to change your Logic App (for dev testing), you can create another Logic App, which would act in the capacity of the library that you desire: you can call it passing a JSON as a parameter, the Logic App will execute the expression and return the result.